# MVC: всё как классы?

Tags: ооп, php, mvc

Насколько я смотрю, в подавляющем большинстве PHP фреймворков, работающих по парадигме MVC, все контроллеры, виды и модели сделаны как классы. Как вы считаете, это обязательно для хорошего приложения?
К примеру, я использую классы для всех моделей (хотя реально они не везде настолько полезны), а вот контроллеры и представления - не классы. Контроллер - просто сценарий, представление - тоже просто шаблон (на Blitz'е), ну и для него есть кусочек обработки всяких циклов и условий отображения в контроллере (как бы контроллер вида). Хотя, я ещё не опытный и не познал дзена ООП, но всё равно, если вот я у себя не получаю пользы с классом для C и V, то нормально ли это?

Comment: Вы тесты пишете?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, пока нет.

Comment: @Constuct Поэтому и пользы от `C` и `V` не ощущаете :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, можете пояснить вкратце, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Construct

- Практически вся прелесть `MVC,` за исключением разделения областей ответственности, заключается в простоте тестирования.

- Модели вместе с их фабриками можно легко протестировать отдельно от логики `Controller / View.`

- А далее (если модель хорошо написана), то она тривиально `mock'ается` и обычно можно сразу же написать пачку приличных тестов на контроллер, а то и написать их раньше самого контроллера, следуя `TDD.`

- Тестить `View` обычно либо очень тяжело, либо просто бессмысленно, поэтому правильный `View` должен быть минимальным с точки зрения количества логики в нем.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, спасибо за ответ, про TDD я вообще не в курсе. Буду на этой недели вкуривать. А ещё у меня нету никаких фабрик моделей, ужас :(

Comment: @Construct Вообще говоря, перед тем как добавлять "фабрики ради фабрик", задумайтесь, нужны ли они вам. Я-то привел их как пример, а для вашего набора моделей введение фабрик может быть совершенно лишним, если и без них все хорошо выглядит.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Главная идея MVC заключается в разделении всей логики на три отдельных компонента, соответственно, если у вас, насколько это возможно, исполняется это "простое" условие, ваше приложение придерживается парадигмы MVC, независимо от того, используете ли вы ООП или нет.

по поводу

> "Только классы дадут расширяемый и повторно используемый код"
>
> "реально гибкий код - это ООП"

Гибкость кода практически на 100% зависит от программиста и я бы с вами очень сильно поспорил в этом вопросе. Да, безусловно, ООП - отличный инструмент, который **иногда** просто жизненно необходим, но, при этом, зачастую, используется кем нибудь, как нибудь и повсеместно.

В общем, половлю камней, но - не ООП делает код гибким и хорошим, а программист, никогда не стоит об этом забывать.

Answer (score 2):

Только классы дадут расширяемый и повторно используемый код... так что учитесь и прибудет с вами счастье ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще, реально гибкий код - это ООП. Вы столкнетесь с этим когда будете перепиливать, что-либо большое)

Comment: Сейчас подумал хорошенько и понял - действительно, в моём случае только поначалу кажется, что для контроллеров не нужны классы. А вот если подумать а необходимости смены чего-то большого, как вы и сказали, типа шаблонизатора, то придётся фигово.

Answer (score -3):

Вообще в паттерне MVC обязательно должен быть лишь один класс - роутер, обрабатывающий URL и выдающий контент на основе этого самого URL. Букет остальных классов - это ваш выбор. Здесь лишь вопрос о хорошем стиле, удобности и переносимости кода.

Comment: А вот роутера у меня то и нету)  
точнее, там просто несколько строчек, определяющих, чё делать, по адресу. Ну то есть это и есть роутер. Хватает.

Comment: Интересно, почему тогда `MVC` расшифровывается как `Model-View-Controller`, а не `Router`.

Comment: @Asen

- "Подробнее" в коммент не влезет, поэтому читайте `GoF` :)

- В фундаментальном паттерне `MVC` нет никаких упоминаний о роутерах и `url'ах`. Тем более, что `MVC,` например, может использоваться при построении архитектуры десктопного приложения, соответственно, `URL` здесь совершенно не в тему.

Comment: @Asen Не очень понял фразу про то, что *тем не менее `MVC` остается таким, каким был,* ну да ладно :)

Comment: @Construct - если вы о классике вида index.php, на который приходят все запросы, то этот шаблон называется "front controller"

Comment: @AlexWindHope, да, у меня он и есть, и я знаю его название. А что, с ним, собственно, не так? Отличное и удобное решение, никак не мешающее MVC, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @Constructr - я не писал обратного, просто, раз вы его идентифицировали как роутер, думал что вы не знаете что это и как называется. Это не был камень в ваш огород, просто уточнение фразы, вот и все

Comment: Нет, фронтконтроллер то ясен пень понятен)  
другое дело, что может я не очень понимаю, что такое роутер...  
я думаю, что это система, которой можно универсально давать задачи роутинга. То есть вот у меня придётся для замены поведения менять код фронтеонтроллера, а если роутер, то там только правила менять. Типа как в Zend Framework.  
Сказал так потому, что, в принципе, фронт контроллер и исполняет его задачи. То есть не только его задачи, но и его задачи тоже :)  
Но "роутера" как такового нет, мне не нужна сложная система роутинга, это могу сказать с уверенностью и на будущее.

Comment: @Construct - что-то типа того :)

FrontController это просто централизированная точка входа в ваше приложение. Router это то, что должно быть вызвано FC'ом для определения дальнейшей судьбы конкретного запроса :)

Поэтому роутер у вас, в том или ином виде, тоже есть, если вы об этом.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, угу, естественно. Просто @Asen говорил о целом классе, что уж мне точно не нужно. Всё-таки, думаю, не роутер основа MVC.